# How may I systematically go through the possible errors to make the setup possible?

Tags: c++, cmake, build

[additional / revised info is provided in this post to incorporate possible comments]

For any experienced users,

I would like to set up the MeTA tool in my Mac OSX according to the following doc: https://meta-toolkit.org/setup-guide.html

Step 1: `brew update`

Step 2: `brew install cmake jemalloc lzlib icu4c`

Output 2:

```
> Warning: Treating cmake as a formula. For the cask, use
> homebrew/cask/cmake Warning: cmake 3.18.4 is already installed and
> up-to-date To reinstall 3.18.4, run `brew reinstall cmake` Warning:
> jemalloc 5.2.1_1 is already installed and up-to-date To reinstall
> 5.2.1_1, run `brew reinstall jemalloc` Warning: lzlib 1.11 is already installed and up-to-date To reinstall 1.11, run `brew reinstall lzlib`
> ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/icu4c-67.1.high_sierra.bott
> ==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/0720bd47f020d5ca895ae
> ######################################################################## 100.0%
> ==> Pouring icu4c-67.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
> ==> Caveats icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing
> else).
> 
> If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:   echo 'export
> PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >>
> /Users/yuenfannie/.bash_profile   echo 'export
> PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >>
> /Users/yuenfannie/.bash_profile
> 
> For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:   export
> LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"   export
> CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"
> 
> ==> Summary   /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1: 258 files, 71.4MB
> ==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now... Error: Permission denied @ apply2files -
> /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logo10.pfb
```

Step 3: `git clone https://github.com/meta-toolkit/meta.git`

Step 4: `cd meta/`

Step 5:

```
# set up submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Step 6:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cp ../config.toml .
```

Step 7:

```
# configure and build the project
CXX=clang++ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DICU_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/icu4c
make
```

previous Output 7:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/libz.dylib (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib - found
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib - found
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib - found
-- Found LibLZMA: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.dylib (found version "5.0.4") 
-- Searching for ICU 58.2
CMake Warning (dev) at deps/meta-cmake/FindOrBuildICU.cmake:31 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  CMake variable ICU_ROOT is set to:

    /usr/local/opt/icu4c

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (FindOrBuildICU)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- ICU not found; attempting to build it...
-- ICU include dirs: /Users/yuenfannie/meta/build/deps/icu-58.2/include
-- ICU libraries: icui18n;icuuc;icudata
-- Locating libc++...
-- Located libc++: /usr/lib/libc++.dylib
-- Located libc++ include path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/
--     Locating libc++'s abi...
--     Found libc++abi: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
-- Found LIBCXX: /usr/lib/libc++.dylib  
-- Using regular malloc; consider installing jemalloc
-- Performing Test META_HAS_ALIGNED_ALLOC
-- Performing Test META_HAS_ALIGNED_ALLOC - Failed
-- Performing Test META_HAS_POSIX_MEMALIGN
-- Performing Test META_HAS_POSIX_MEMALIGN - Failed
CMake Error at deps/meta-cmake/kludges/AlignedAlloc.cmake:54 (message):
  Failed to find a suitable aligned allocation routine
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  deps/meta-cmake/CompilerKludges.cmake:18 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:120 (CompilerKludges)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/yuenfannie/meta/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/yuenfannie/meta/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

current Output 7:

```
-- Searching for ICU 58.2
CMake Warning (dev) at deps/meta-cmake/FindOrBuildICU.cmake:31 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  CMake variable ICU_ROOT is set to:

    /usr/local/opt/icu4c

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (FindOrBuildICU)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found ICU: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.dylib;/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.dylib;/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.dylib (Required is at least version "58.2") 
-- ICU version found is 67.1.0, expected 58.2; attempting to build ICU from scratch...
-- ICU include dirs: /Users/yuenfannie/meta/build/deps/icu-58.2/include
-- ICU libraries: icui18n;icuuc;icudata
-- Locating libc++...
-- Located libc++: /usr/lib/libc++.dylib
-- Located libc++ include path: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/
--     Locating libc++'s abi...
--     Found libc++abi: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
-- Using jemalloc: /usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.dylib
CMake Error at deps/meta-cmake/kludges/AlignedAlloc.cmake:54 (message):
  Failed to find a suitable aligned allocation routine
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  deps/meta-cmake/CompilerKludges.cmake:18 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:120 (CompilerKludges)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/yuenfannie/meta/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/yuenfannie/meta/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How may I systematically go through the possible errors to make the setup possible? Your suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The setup guide you linked explicitly states to do `brew install cmake jemalloc lzlib icu4c`. Clearly you didn't do that, because CMake says: `-- Using regular malloc; consider installing jemalloc`. What happens when you follow the setup guide?

Comment: Hi @Darhuuk, thanks for your comment based on the CMake output. The setup guide was strictly followed. I revised the post with all the steps and corresponding outputs. Is the **Error** in running `brew install cmake jemalloc lzlib icu4c` prohibit the setup? If so, what should be done?